# In Ag-Grid Function is not calling

Tags: angular8

I am using customize `Ag-grid` ,inside that using input field type number on keypress , I am calling a function but it is not calling in my keypress

On keypress I am calling a following function:

```
field: "TotalQty", headerName: "TOTAL KIT QTY",
editable: true,
filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
 cellRenderer: params => {
    return '<input (keypress)="onCellValueChanged($event)" type="number" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off">';
    },
```

I want when I enter a number in `ag-grid`  my function get called.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cellEditor, not a cellRenderer